# How to get coordinates of values in a matrix that are considered as abnormal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to get the coordinate of value that it has differed from other values in that column. Here is a simple example of the array.

```
arr = np.ones((4,4))
arr[:2, :2] = 0
```

This will give you a 4 by 4 matrix, and the value at [2,0], [2,1], [3,0], [3,1] are considered abnormal since it has a different value than other values in that column. I want to get those coordinates as the output. Also, if you think this is as an image it will look like this:

```
0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

The last two ones in the first column will be considered abnormal. Here are some more examples of arrays and abnormal coordinates:

```
arr[:3, :1] = 0 =====> (0,3) 
arr[:, :1] = 0 =======> no abnormal 
arr[:3, -1] = 0 ======> (3,3)
```

I have tried some ways to find the number of unique values in that column and locate the columns where include more than two values. However, it is hard for me to get the rows.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the rule that makes a value "normal" or "abnormal"? In your example, the first two columns have an equal number of `0` and `1`, why is `0` considered to be the "normal" value and `1` the "abnormal" one?

Comment: Different value than other values in that column. as well as same values within the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Find indices of column values that don't match the first value:

- Given your sample data
- Iterate through each column

  - Find there first value in the column
  - Use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) to find the location where values don't equal the first value.

```py
non_matching_value_indices = list()
for i, col in enumerate(image1.T):  # iterate through each column
    loc_0 = col[0]  # extract the first value
    locs = np.where(col != loc_0)[0]  # find locations in the column that do not match the first value
    if len(locs) > 0:  # check if the list is empty
        locs = [[x, i] for x in locs]  # add the column index to the row location
        non_matching_value_indices.append(locs)  # if the list is not empty add it to non_matching_value_indices

print(non_matching_value_indices)

[[[2, 0], [3, 0]], [[2, 1], [3, 1]]]
```

### Add to a dict for clarity

```py
def find_value_indices_not_matching_first_value(input_array: np.array) -> dict:
    non_matching_value_indices = dict()
    for i, col in enumerate(input_array.T):
        locs = list()
        loc_0 = col[0]
        locs = np.where(col != loc_0)[0]
        if len(locs) > 0:
            locs = [[x, i] for x in locs]
            non_matching_value_indices[f'col_{i}'] = locs
            
    return non_matching_value_indices


find_value_indices_not_matching_first_value(image1)
{'col_0': [[2, 0], [3, 0]], 'col_1': [[2, 1], [3, 1]]}
```

### Test

```py
import numpy as np

# test array
np.random.seed(3)
test = np.random.randint(10, size=(8, 4))

array([[8, 9, 3, 8],
       [8, 0, 5, 3],
       [9, 9, 5, 7],
       [6, 0, 4, 7],
       [8, 1, 6, 2],
       [2, 1, 3, 5],
       [8, 1, 8, 7],
       [8, 1, 0, 5]])

find_value_indices_not_matching_first_value(test)

{'col_0': [[2, 0], [3, 0], [5, 0]],
 'col_1': [[1, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1]],
 'col_2': [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [4, 2], [6, 2], [7, 2]],
 'col_3': [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 3], [5, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3]]}
```

## Find indices of 1's when 0 is in the column:

```py
def fine_indices_of_1_when_0_in_column(input_array: np.array) -> dict:
    non_matching_value_indices = dict()
    for i, col in enumerate(input_array.T):
        if 0 in col:
            locs = np.where(col != 0)[0]
            if len(locs) > 0:
                locs = [[x, i] for x in locs]
                non_matching_value_indices[f'col_{i}'] = locs
    
    return non_matching_value_indices


# test array
np.random.seed(3)
test = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(8, 4))
test[:, 3] = 1

array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# run function
fine_indices_of_1_when_0_in_column(test)

{'col_0': [[2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0]],
 'col_1': [[2, 1], [3, 1], [5, 1]],
 'col_2': [[0, 2], [5, 2], [6, 2]]}
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you so much